# Adding duration for custom toast message in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Able to display Toast message in Lightning. But I need to set duration for lightning toast messages how can I do it. I need to display toast message for few seconds in screen..now what's happening is it will stay in screen forever..after showing msg it should appear .. for below line of code.

I have tried  like this:

```
 showNotification : function(component,variant,title,messageBody,mode){
    component.find('message').showToast({
        "variant": variant,
        "title": title,
        "message": messageBody,
         duration:' 5000',
        "mode": mode
    });
```

---

Components:

```
  <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="message"/>
```

---

Js side:

```
  if(component.get('v.phoneQSelected') === '--None--'){
        helper.showNotification(component,"Error","Missing Value","What phone Q did the call originate on?","sticky");
        return;
    }
```

---

```
 showNotification : function(component,variant,title,messageBody,mode){
    component.find('message').showToast({
        "variant": variant,
        "title": title,
        "message": messageBody,

        "mode": mode
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, the only way to specify a duration is [force:showToast](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/documentation).

```
$A.get("e.force:showToast")
    .setParams({duration: 5000, ... })
    .fire();
```

The lightning:notificationsLibrary is the preferred mechanism, but does not allow you to specify anything other than until dismissed, dismissed or 3 seconds, or 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
  if(component.get('v.phoneQSelected') === '--None--'){
    helper.showNotification(component,"Error","Missing Value","What phone Q did the call originate on?","**dismissible**");
    return;
}
```

You need to change the value for the parameter **mode** to either **dismissible** or **pester**. Refer this link for more info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/documentation)

In the specification tab you can find detailed information for each attribute.

Answer (score 1):

From docs for [lightning : notification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:notificationsLibrary/documentation).

> mode: Determines how persistent the toast is. The default is
>   dismissable. Valid modes are:
>
> 1. dismissable: Remains visible until you press the close button or 3
>      seconds has elapsed, whichever comes first.
> 2. pester: Remains visible until the close button is clicked.
> 3. sticky: Remains visible for 3 seconds.

There is no extra parameter to control the timing of the toasts. The reason being showing toast and looks are controlled by lightning container. (one.app) and the container does not provide you that flexibility. The reason being SF wants you to stick to the standard SF guidelines. This makes it uniform and all toast in Standard SF are 3 secs long.

You have to design your own toast component using [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/toast/), once it's your component you can control your duration using Javascript.